# Windows 10, Anaconda, Jupyter, and DLL error on importing Seaborn though it's installed

Tags: python, windows, import, jupyter

Please help me solve this odd issue. Thanks in advance. I have installed on MacOS and Ubuntu Linux, the same Anaconda and Jupyter Notebook of 64 bit, for their respective OS's. MacOS is the host, and Linux and Windows 10 are VM's. On the Windows 10 VM, I have also installed all the same, but when I run known good Python code with data set, that works great on a completely different Windows 10 machine, and also prefect with no errors and expected results on my MacOS host, and Linux VM. But when I run on Windows 10 VM, I get errors on the Seaborn import.

I've tried the pip/conda install and update for seaborn

Uninstalling everything Python, Anacodna, Jupyter, etc and reinstalling fresh on the Windows 10 VM on host, to no avail, I get the same error(s).

Error - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

Comment: I've conda uninstalled and reinstalled seaborn, and matploylib, and others, and now I get pas tthe seaborn issue, but now have the same exact problem with sklearn, where I'm importing the standardscaler lib, and its the same thing, yet, conda and pip uninstalled and reinstalled and kernel restarts and all, nothing, same error about the DLL missing, etc. Very frustrating

Comment: After much remove, install, with both pip and conda, trying in jupyter notebook and lab,many restarts of the kernel, as well and breakdown and startup of the apps, along with targeted removal of and reinstalls of other packages, I;m still left with getting the error on the scipy: from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, and error previously  mentioned, for my Windows 10 VM install of Conda/Jupyter. HELP! Looks like I have more serious surgery to purge whats bad and replace with good, but not sure what's a safe proven method to address.

Comment: I seem to have other things interfering within the Win10 anacona/jupyter env, like Sypder, something I tried to use months ago, but was too buggy to proceed with. When I fire up Anaconda thorugh the Navigator, and open Jupyter Notebook, it displays that Syder is running, even though I uninstalled all that. I think I'm going to have to rip out everything, and its not just going to be with uninstall command lines with pip and condo or control panel. Has anyone had to go this deep to clear out old stuff, just shy of starting a new Windows 10 VM fresh? Thoughts?